# Cat unix command multithread implementation

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, concatenation, cat

Hi im trying to implement faster cat than the one provided.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUF_SIZE 1024*1024*1024

char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_var = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_var2 = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int readed = 0;
/*
    Read characters from standard input and saves them to buffer
*/
void *consumer(void *data) {
    int r;
    while(1) {
        //---------CRITICAL CODE--------------
        //------------REGION------------------
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (readed > 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond_var2, &mutex);
        }
        r = read(0, buffer, BUF_SIZE);
        readed = r;

        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_var);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        //------------------------------------

        if (r == -1){
            printf("Error reading\n");
        }  
        else if (r == 0) {
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    }
}

/*
    Print chars readed by consumer from standard input to standard output
*/
void *out_producer(void *data) {
    int w;
    while(1){    
        //---------CRITICAL CODE--------------
        //-------------REGION-----------------
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        if (readed == 0)
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond_var, &mutex);
        }
        w = write(1, buffer, readed); 
        readed = 0;
        pthread_cond_signal(&cond_var2);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        //------------------------------------ 

        if (w == -1){
            printf("Error writing\n");
        } 
        else if (w == 0) {
            pthread_exit(NULL);
        }
    }
}
```

What would you suggest to make it faster? 
Any ideas? 
I was thinking about the BUF_SIZE, what would you think would be optimal size of buffer?

Main just makes the threads:

```
int main() {
    //  Program RETURN value
    int return_value = 0;

    //  in - INPUT thread
    //  out - OUTPUT thread
    pthread_t in, out;

    //  Creating in thread - should read from standard input (0)
    return_value = pthread_create(&in , NULL, consumer, NULL);
    if (return_value != 0) {
        printf("Error creating input thread exiting with code error: %d\n", return_value);
        return return_value;
    }

    //  Creating out thread - should write to standard output (1)
    return_value = pthread_create(&out, NULL, out_producer, NULL);
    if (return_value != 0) {
        printf("Error creating output thread exiting with code error: %d\n", return_value);
        return return_value;
    }

    return_value = pthread_join(in, NULL);
    return_value = pthread_join(out, NULL);

    return return_value;
}
```

Comment: 1GB is definitely not a reasonable buffer size....

Comment: and what would you suggest? i will by also using cat on files with size more than 10GB

Comment: Why do you think threads will make `cat` faster?

Comment: I dont know im just doing some experiments for fun and i wanted to learn how to work with threads.

Comment: What SzG said. If this is not just an exercise in multi-threaded programming but a real attempt to make cat faster, I think you're headed down the wrong path. To know how to really make it faster we'd need to know more about your usage case. If it's used with pipes, pipes are almost certainly the limiting factor but you may be able to improve things (in a Linux-specific way) by changing the pipe buffer size and using the `splice`-family functions.

Comment: Can you explain why? Thanks.

Comment: If on the other hand it's just for copying disk files, you're almost surely going to be bound by disk io.

Comment: OK then. Threads only make sense if you have multiple cores and you have some computationally intensive tasks that you can run parallelly. `cat` needs exactly zero compuation.

Comment: What about adding more buffers? so I can read and write paralely.Would that make it faster?

Comment: @Yetti: The usage case really matters. Standard `cat` is fundamentally sequential (it works with non-seekable, non-block-based files such as pipes and sockets and character devices) so there's essentially no opportunity for parallelism. On the other hand if you're using it like `cp` where both the input file and `stdout` are files on disk, you could break it up into blocks and work on all blocks concurrently (e.g. with `pread` and `pwrite`). But this still won't help you for huge files that can't be fully cached unless you can make disk access concurrent (e.g. with RAID).

Answer (score 3):

How exactly is adding threads to `cat` going to make it faster? You can't just throw parallelism at any program and expect it to run faster.

Cat basically just transports every line of input (usually from a file) to output. Since it's important that the lines are in order, you have to use mutual exclusion to avoid racing.

The upper bound of the speed (the fastest that `cat` can run) in parallel cannot be higher than `cat` in serial, since every thread must perform the serial actions, along with the cost of synchronization.

Comment: It can be *slightly* faster since the read of the next unit of data can take place in parallel with the write of the previous.

Comment: @R.., the operating system should notice by itself (or get an explicit hint from the program) that it is reading sequentially, and schedule read-ahead appropiately.

Comment: @vonbrand: It can do that, but it still can't schedule reading into the userspace process's address space ahead of time. This is the only point where I see the *potential* (still very limited) for gains from a multithreaded implementation.

Comment: actually on >1GB files im getting slightly better results than with os cat command ( i added second buffer and made buffers size 1024*1024/4) so while first buffer is being filled second is beeing written. but still its difference is about +-0,0x sec